# insert value from a textbox to a particular cell in excel in C#.NET

Tags: c#, excel

```
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
       //Static File From Base Path...........
       //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "TestExcel.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
       //Dynamic File Using Uploader...........
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\madduru\\Desktop\\Design.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); ;
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

       excelSheet.Cells[4, 6] = Results.Text;
       excelBook.Save();
       excelBook.Close(true, null, null);
       excelApp.Quit();
```

I'm trying to insert a value(number) given by the user to a particular cell in excel and trying to save it. My code doesn't save the value to that particular cell [4,6]. Compatibility error with excel workbook.
Any help is hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I like to suggest using [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) for any excel work in c# as it make it very simple if you are allowed to add nuget packages to your project. *Disclaimer: I am in no way associated with ClosedXML, I just think it is a great simplified package for writing to excel

Comment: Your code currently opens the file in Read-only mode.  This may have something to do with the error you are getting.  I got it running on my machine just fine, except I got a dialogue box asking me if I wanted to save it with same name.